# Is there a physical interpretation of the exterior derivative of the current one-form?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry

I understand the vanishing exterior derivative  of Faraday tensor gives you the sourcefree Maxwell's equations but was wondering if there was a physical interpretation to the exterior derivative of the current one form?

Comment: $dj$ is a two-form. Doesn't mean a thing. The co-differential, however, means something. It is the mismatch in electric charge conservation.

Comment: could you elaborate or refer me to some explaination on what you mean by mismatch in electric charge conservation?